# How to check whether a method parameter is Nullable<> using reflection if it's also an "out" parameter?

Tags: c#, reflection, parameters, nullable, out

With method signatures like:

```
public interface TestInterface
{
    void SampleMethodOut(out int? nullableInt);
    void SampleMethod(int? nullableInt);
}
```

I'm using `typeof(TestInterface).GetMethods()[1].GetParameters()[0].ParameterType` to get the type, and then checking `IsGenericType` and `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType`. How can I do this with the method with the out parameter?

Comment: For the one that isn't an out parameter IsGenericType is true and Nullable.GetUnderlyingType returns Int32, but for the out parameter it's false and null.

Comment: So for the non-out parameter, `ParameterType` returns `typeof(Nullable<int>)` -- what does it return for the out parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doh, ignore my previous answer.

You use `Type.IsByRef`, and call `Type.GetElementType()` if so:

```
var type = method.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType;
if (type.IsByRef)
{
    // Remove the ref/out-ness
    type = type.GetElementType();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for everyone just finding this page

c# documentation pages show a concise way of doing just that
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types#how-to-identify-a-nullable-value-type

```
Console.WriteLine($"int? is {(IsNullable(typeof(int?)) ? "nullable" : "non nullable")} type");
Console.WriteLine($"int is {(IsNullable(typeof(int)) ? "nullable" : "non-nullable")} type");

bool IsNullable(Type type) => Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) != null;

// Output:
// int? is nullable type
// int is non-nullable type
```

Using reflection, this is how you get your parameter types:

```
typeof(MyClass).GetMethod("MyMethod").GetParameters()[0].ParameterType;
```